# ffmpeg creates unwatchable video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a bunch of images in the format 000.png to 014.png. I used this command

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -i %03d.png o.avi
```

I expect a 1 fps video thats 15 seconds long. I get that however the first 4 seconds I get a blank screen on the 4th second I get one image which is 000.png. If I seek I get no video. I'm watching using vlc 2.0.8

This is the output it gives me.

How do I encode this so I get a proper video?

```
Input #0, image2, from '%03d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 1280x1024 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 5:4], 25 fps, 25tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'o.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, avi, to 'o.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf55.16.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 1280x1024 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> mpeg4)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   15 fps=0.0 q=7.0 Lsize=     692kB time=00:00:15.00 bitrate= 378.0kbits/s
video:686kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.872085%
```

Comment: Try other players (and `ffplay`) to rule out that VLC is the culprit – it often is from my experiences.

Comment: @slhck: wow, this is the first video vlc failed to play properly. ffplay and windows play it properly. hmm everytime i try to specify a vcodec ffmpeg fails. Sometimes because of the size of the images (1280x1024)

Comment: That depends on the codec, but you shouldn't have any issue with recent codecs (i.e. MPEG-4 or VP8 etc.) – maybe you can edit the question and show the full uncut console output of a failing command

Comment: @slhck: H263 is MPEG-4? It had a problem as well. I'll try on linux later

Comment: H.263 is a different, older codec compared to MPEG-4. It's very likely that the actual codec does not matter and the VLC issue is more general.